# Mixed models: How to treat random factors that are nested within a condition

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

Consider the following experimental design with a within-subject condition (`cond`) that has two levels (`A` and `B`). In each condition, participants are asked to rate a series of stimuli on a scale. Importantly, there is only one unique type of stimulus (`S0`) in the `A` condition, but three in the other condition. The `S0` stimulus does not belong to the population of stimuli from the condition `B`.

The data looks like this:

```r
library(data.table)
n <- 10 # number of participants
X <- data.table(id   = rep(1:n, each = 12),
                cond = rep(rep(c("A", "B"), each = 6), n),
                stimuli = rep(c(rep(c("S0"), 6), rep(c("S1", "S2", "S3"), each = 2)), n),
                rating = rnorm(12*n))

# data for the first participant
# > head(X, n = 12)
#     id cond stimuli     rating
#  1:  1    A      S0  1.2013984
#  2:  1    A      S0 -1.4694679
#  3:  1    A      S0  0.7244075
#  4:  1    A      S0 -0.8869662
#  5:  1    A      S0  1.2883127
#  6:  1    A      S0  0.9760857
#  7:  1    B      S1 -1.8132060
#  8:  1    B      S1 -0.7143217
#  9:  1    B      S2 -1.1468717
# 10:  1    B      S2 -0.2148807
# 11:  1    B      S3 -0.6231036
# 12:  1    B      S3 -0.1853305
```

I would like to treat both the participant's `id` and `stimuli` as random factors. However, I am not sure how to deal with the fact that `stimuli` can only be considered a random factor in the `B` condition.

This is the Linear-mixed-model I have relied on:

```r
library(lmerTest)
mdl <- lmer(rating ~ cond + (1|id) + (1|stimuli), data = X)
summary(mdl)
```

Is this the right approach?

Comment: What is your motivation for treating stimuli as random ? From the description it sounds like it should be a fixed effect.

Comment: From my understanding, treating stimuli as random would allow me to generalize the results to more stimuli from the same population, and not only to the 3 stimuli used here.

Comment: The estimated variance of the random effect would be very unreliable with only 3 observations in the same way as if I sampled 3 student's heights in a school it would not provide a good estimate of the variance of all students heights. Generalizing to the wider population from a sample of only 3 is a very questionable thing to do.

Comment: @RobertLong Assuming this is just a simplified dataset example and that there are many more stimuli in the real dataset for the `B` condition, how could it be analyzed?